# Recording and playing audio with iPod

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipod

I'm trying to record and play audio in an universal app. The AVAudioSession configuration is:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil]; 
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;  
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category);
```

This is working fine for devices with built-in microphone. But in a third generation iPod I am experiencing random undesired behaviours. Sometimes all works fine, and sometimes it happens only when the earphones with the integrated mic are plugged-in. In this case, is not possible to hear any sound in the app without the earphones.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd generation of iPod Touch doesn't have a built-in microphone. The only way to have one is to plug your headphones with a mic. 
The only generation of iPod Touch with a built-in microphone is the 4th.

You can check if inputRecording is available :

```
UInt32 propertySize, micConnected;
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioInputAvailable, &propertySize, &micConnected);
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, but this didn't solve my problem. The issue is that I'm loosing the external speaker sound  when I set audio category to kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord to allow recording in the iPod third gen. I am detecting the device model and the microphone plug/unplug and I try to reset the audio session category, but I cannot recover the speaker sound. Any clue?

Comment: @LoDani On the iPod Touch 3rd gen, what's the result when you get kAudioSessionProperty_AudioInputAvailable ? Your problem appears when you unplug the headset ?

Comment: It returns true (micConnected != 0) despite the headset was connected or not. But I get  the right result asking for [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] inputIsAvailable]. And yes, my problems arise when I unplug the headset after make a recording. I  tried to change AudioCategory and AudioRoute properties after detecting the unplug without no result.

Comment: @LoDani if this link doesn't help you should open a ticket at Apple. Maybe it's a bug. https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/ipad/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingRouteChanges/HandlingRouteChanges.html